# SymmetricDS : File sync on same filename to different path

Tags: symmetricds

I have 2 files with same name but sync to different path at the target, but only 1 file get synced down at the target. I noticed in file_snapshot CRC32_CHECKSUM are the same for both filename. Is it the correct behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a fix for this that will be released in 3.8.28 but here is a link to the patch for 3.8.27.   You will also need two routers and two file routers (which you may already have).

https://support.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/patches/3.8/patch-0003197.jar

Comment: I do a workaround by appending the files with node_id in source, then when send to target, I set the file target name to remove the node_id, so I get the same filename I want in the target.